# Google App Engine TextSearch Update/Delete 15,000 per minute quota limit exception

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gae-search

We are getting following Quota limit exception when we are updating textsearch document,

com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$OverQuotaException: The API call search.IndexDocument() required more quota than is available. 
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:365)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:233)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)

and code is

public SearchService searchService = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService();

public Index index = searchService.getIndex(IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("contacts"));

Document.Builder docs = Document.newBuilder();

docs.addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("first_name_start").setText(first_name.substring(0, 1)));

index.put(docs);

any suggestion towards resolving it?

Comment: simple solution could be increasing quote,is there a option through which we can increase or request an increase with google?

Comment: Do believe you are actually exceeding 15000 update/delete operations per minute?

Comment: Could be 10GB per namespace limit exception also.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, one solution to hitting either a space or a throughput quota on App Engine is to get in touch with Google. You can find information about how to do that [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#search).

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it was INDEX Size>10GB, that threw this exception.